# How to check if a template argument is of a particular templated type (multiple type parameters)

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I asked a question yesterday ([How to find out if a type is a templated type of any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962110/how-to-find-out-if-a-type-is-a-templated-type-of-any-type)) about how to check for a particular template argument when that argument is a templated class of any type. And the solution was something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Animal{};

template <typename T>
struct IsAnimalOfAnyType
{
    constexpr bool value() { return false; }
};

template <typename T>
struct IsAnimalOfAnyType<Animal<T>>
{
    constexpr bool value() { return true; }
};
```

However this works with single-argument templates, but I'm trying to do the following:

```cpp
template <typename T, T integer, typename U>
struct Animal{};

template <typename T>
struct IsAnimalOfAnyType
{
    constexpr bool value() { return false; }
};


template <typename T> 
struct IsAnimalOfAnyType<Animal<T>>
{
    constexpr bool value() { return true; }
};

/* Animal needs to be Animal<T, integer, U>,
  but 'T', 'integer' and 'U' template arguments are not available here,
  and if I have these arguments here
  then IsAnimalOfAnyType is no longer a specialization and it won't compile
*/
```

As far as I understand it the difference is that struct Animal:

1. Has multiple template arguments
   and
2. One of the arguments is not a type, but an integer

How to go about doing this?

Comment: Since C++17, you can do `<auto integer>` instead of `<typename T, T integer>`. That might simplify some things. Although it depends on the exact use case. You might have `<typename T, T first, T second>` which is not the same as `<auto first, auto second>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare all the template parameters required by `Animal` for the specialization.

```
template <typename T, T integer, typename U> 
struct IsAnimalOfAnyType<Animal<T, integer, U>>
{
    constexpr bool value() { return true; }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VGhHKtvpaZD1YUtM)

Comment: Is that still a specialization of template <typename T> struct IsAnimalOfAnyType { }  even though it has three template arguments instead of one? Is that full or partial?

Comment: @Zebrafish It's partial specialization. For full specialization it would be sth like `template <> struct IsAnimalOfAnyType<...> { ... };`.