# How to tell if template type is an instance of a non-variadic template class?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

This question is awful similar to [How to tell if template type is an instance of a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012938/how-to-tell-if-template-type-is-an-instance-of-a-template-class)

I would like to detect if a template parameter is from one particular template class that has no variadic template arguments.

```cpp
template<class U, class S>
struct A{};

template<class T>
struct B {
  B() {
    if constexpr (T == A) {
      // T is a template instantiation of `A`.
    } else {
    }
  }
};
```

I can't change `A`'s definition. I can change `B`'s definition to have additional template parameters.

How do I implement (T == A) given the restriction of not knowing A's `U` and `S`?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a partial specialization here.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class U, class S>
struct A{};

template<class T>
struct B {
    B() {
        std::cout << "None-A implementation\n";
    }
};

template<class U, class S>
struct B<A<U, S>> {
    B() {
        std::cout << "A implementation\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    B<int> b1;
    B<A<int, int>> b2;
}
```

You have the option of leaving the default-case without an implementation.

Or you can have a fallback implementation for any none-A classes like here.

If the partial specialization forces too much code duplication you can also extract the detection part to it's own template variable like this.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class U, class S>
struct A{};

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_A_instatiation = false;

template <class U, class S>
constexpr bool is_A_instatiation<A<U, S>> = true;

template<class T>
struct B {
    B() {
        if constexpr (is_A_instatiation<T>) {
            std::cout << "A instatiation!\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "none-A instatiation!\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    B<int> b1;
    B<A<int, int>> b2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
template<class T>
struct B{/*default implementation*/};

template<class U,class S>
struct B<A<U,S>>{/*Specified implementation*/};
```

Answer (score 0):

- A<T,U>: you already know it and search key
- B<...>: variadic types which may include A<T,U> - known type

And you want to search A<T,U> in B<...>

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct A {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Ts>
struct B {
    static constexpr bool value = ((std::is_same_v< A<T, U>, Ts> || ... ));
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << 
    B<int,float, int, int, float, A<int,float>>::value << '\n'<<
    B<int,float, int, int, float>::value <<std::endl;
}
```